# SVG Moon Phases

Tags: javascript, svg, astronomy

For a larger project, I'd like to add the moon phase on a hover date.  I found javascript that calculates the moon phase and I also found the SVG moon phase solution posted by @Alexandr_TT at [Create waxing crescent moon in svg using path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062563/create-waxing-crescent-moon-in-svg-using-path).

The javascript mathematically calculates the moon phase:

```
function getMoonPhase(year, month, day) {
    var c = e = jd = b = 0;

    if (month < 3) {
    year--;
    month += 12;
    }
    ++month;
    c = 365.25 * year;
    e = 30.6 * month;
    jd = c + e + day - 694039.09; //jd is total days elapsed
    jd /= 29.5305882; //divide by the moon cycle
    b = parseInt(jd); //int(jd) -> b, take integer part of jd
    jd -= b; //subtract integer part to leave fractional part of original jd
    b = Math.round(jd * 8); //scale fraction from 0-8 and round
    if (b >= 8 ) {
        b = 0; //0 and 8 are the same so turn 8 into 0
    }

    // 0 => New Moon
    // 1 => Waxing Crescent Moon
    // 2 => Quarter Moon
    // 3 => Waxing Gibbous Moon
    // 4 => Full Moon
    // 5 => Waning Gibbous Moon
    // 6 => Last Quarter Moon
    // 7 => Waning Crescent Moon

    return b;
}
```

Alexandr's SVG is an animation, so my question is can the svg be a snapshot based on the output value of the javascript?

I can certainly generate separate static SVG's for each of the 8 phases. I could also try and modify the solution I found on Github at https://github.com/tingletech/moon-phase, but I am attracted to Alexandr's SVC code because of it's small size.

My goal would be to output the numeric value of the javascript that would then render a visually actuate SVG, in the least amount of code needed to accomplish the goal.

I'm a noob on SVG. The solution on github uses the arc attribute of path in SVG, and it looks like Alexandr is using two intersecting circles. Can the animation be effectively stopped based on the value I get from the javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have a working copy such as this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Moon Phase Today</title>
</head>
<body>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"  viewBox="0 0 73 73" >
  <defs>
   <radialGradient id="RadialGrad" fx="50%" fy="50%" r="65%" spreadMethod="pad">
    <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#E7D68C" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFEED" stop-opacity="1" />
   </radialGradient>
   
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
  <g transform="rotate(-20 35.5 35.5)">
   <circle cx="35.5" cy="35.5" r="35" stroke="none"  fill="url(#RadialGrad)" />
   
   <circle id='layoverCircle' cx="35.5" cy="35.5" r="35" stroke="none" fill="black" />
   
   <rect id="layoverRectangle" style="display: none" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <!-- <animate id="youngMoon" attributeName="cx" values="35.5;-35.5;" begin="1s;oldMoon.end+1s" dur="10s" fill="freeze" /> -->
    <!-- <animate id="oldMoon" attributeName="cx" values="105;35.5;" begin="youngMoon.end+1s" dur="10s"  fill="freeze" />  -->
    
   <!-- </circle>  -->
  </g>
 </svg>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function setState(value, showCircle, showRect) {
   
   let circle = document.getElementById('layoverCircle');
   let rect = document.getElementById('layoverRectangle');
   
   circle.style.display = showCircle ? "block" : "none";
   rect.style.display = showRect ? "block" : "none";
   
   if (showRect) rect.style.transform = value
   if (showCircle) circle.setAttribute("cx", value);
  }
  
  function getMoonPhase(year, month, day) {
   var c = e = jd = b = 0;
   
   if (month < 3) {
    year--;
    month += 12;
   }
   ++month;
   c = 365.25 * year;
   e = 30.6 * month;
   jd = c + e + day - 694039.09; //jd is total days elapsed
   jd /= 29.5305882; //divide by the moon cycle
   b = parseInt(jd); //int(jd) -> b, take integer part of jd
   jd -= b; //subtract integer part to leave fractional part of original jd
   b = Math.round(jd * 8); //scale fraction from 0-8 and round
   if (b >= 8 ) {
    b = 0; //0 and 8 are the same so turn 8 into 0
   }
   
   
   // 0 => New Moon 37.5 [show circle, hide rect]
   // 1 => Waxing Crescent Moon 50.5 [show circle, hide rect]
   // 2 => Quarter Moon //translateX(50%), [display rect, hide circle]
   // 3 => Waxing Gibbous Moon 70.5 [show circle, hide rect]
   // 4 => Full Moon [hide circle and rect]
   // 5 => Waning Gibbous Moon, -15.5 [show circle, hide rect]
   // 6 => Last Quarter Moon //transform: translateX(-50%) [display rect, hide circle]
   // 7 => Waning Crescent Moon 30.5 [show circle, hide rect]
   
   return b;
  }
  
  let d = new Date();
  let i = 0;
  let callback = function () {   
   let phase = getMoonPhase(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate() + i)
   i += 4
   if (phase == 0) setState(37.5, true, false);
   if (phase == 1) setState(50.5, true, false);
   if (phase == 2) setState("translateX(50%)", false, true);
   if (phase == 3) setState(70.5 , true, false);
   if (phase == 4) setState(NaN , false, false);
   if (phase == 5) setState(-15.5, true, false);
   if (phase == 6) setState("translateX(-50%)", false, true);
   if (phase == 7) setState(30.5 , true, false);
   setTimeout(callback, 1000);
  };
  callback();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

setState function is basically what you are looking for. You can also change values in setState to your esthetical needs.

Comment: One small issue is that the zero result (new moon) does not fully cover the circle.

Comment: you can also play the size of the layovercircle to achieve that. In this code I only used positions.

Comment: Not sure why but setting the setState value to 35.5, not 37.5 does the trick for the zero phase.  `if (phase == 0) setState(35.5, true, false);`

Comment: Yeah, you can change the looks for however you want it to look. New moon to me is supposed to be slightly visible, to you it should be pitch dark. So it is a cosmetic preference. Also 35.5 is the position where the 2 circle elements in SVG perfectly align. That is the reason why.

Comment: Well I thought we had it it, but I think the circles are moving in the wrong direction. The current waning gibbous is dark on the left, not the right.  I would not know where to begin to fix that. If you point me to the spot in the code to fix, I'll take a shot! Also, is it possible to add a background image to the SVG such that a jpg of the actual moon surface is on the lit part? Here is an image I found from another example: https://i.imgur.com/OjcPT0P.jpg Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: Well this whole solution won't be a very good substitution to a perfect moon photo, rather than that it will be like a blueprint or 2d drawing. So, you would need to change only cx attribute, which is what I am doing in setState function. When you change that as in the link you sent. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49064801/3554534 in this answer the animate tag has attributes of cx ranging from -35.5 to 105.5. So those are your values to play with on the layoverCircle. You should use a nice debugger like chrome's web inspector should work fine. You can also embed an image into svg, google that.

Comment: The shape of the gibbous moon is wrong. What is represented in your example is the shape it would have if the shadow were caused by a round object passing in front of the moon.

Comment: I did not imply shapes would be perfect, as I said on July 18, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063248/svg-moon-phases/57065845#comment100720446_57065845, you can play with the values if you like.

Comment: The radial gradient effect is nice. But, as usernumber pointed out, the shape of the shadow is wrong - this is more of what an eclipse would look like. It would be more accurate to use a semi circle (an arc in svg) plus an opposite arc (varying the x-radius parameter). While the rotated moon looks elegant, note that the rotation angle changes between waxing and waning, and also between north and south hemisphere viewpoints. A big thanks for your solution though. It led to me learning a lot more about SVG, first to adapt what you done, then to change it.